# Codemagic iOS build issue

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I am trying to compile my app with **Codemagic** for **iOS**. Locally, my environment is:

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows
>   [Version 10.0.18363.657], locale en-US)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 28.0.3)
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)

I have no issue to compile to **Android** app.
However, when I switch to **Codemagic**, and I setup my config to:

```
Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.6
Xcode 11.1
```

I have the following error reported:

```
Compiler message:
lib/app/ui/widgets/color_theme_picker_widget.dart:2:8: Error: Error when reading '../programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_colorpicker-0.3.2/lib/block_picker.dart': No such file or directory

import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/block_picker.dart';
       ^
lib/app/ui/widgets/color_theme_picker_widget.dart:35:28: Error: Method not found: 'BlockPicker'.
                    child: BlockPicker(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/app/ui/widgets/color_theme_picker_widget.dart:35:28: Error: The method 'BlockPicker' isn't defined for the class 'ColorThemePicker'.
 - 'ColorThemePicker' is from 'package:biorhythms/app/ui/widgets/color_theme_picker_widget.dart' ('lib/app/ui/widgets/color_theme_picker_widget.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'BlockPicker'.
```

I would appreciate any feedback,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone came across a similar issue - in my case, it was caused by the following line in my `pubspec.yaml` file - `flutter_colorpicker: any`, since it loads the most recent `flutter_colorpicker` version, where the above file has been removed. SO basically, I had to adjust the code to the most recent version. Also as a general thumb rule - just set your plugin / package version to a specific one e.g. `flutter_colorpicker: ^0.3.2`.